# Detecting junit tests without assertions/verifications

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit

We are looking for a way to fail the build if there are any unit tests with out any sort of verifications. IntelliJ seems to "inspect" these tests by specifying the list of valid assertions.

```html
org.junit.Assert assert.*|fail.*
junit.framework.Assert assert.*|fail.*
org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions assert.*|fail.*
org.assertj.core.api.Assertions assertThat
com.google.common.truth.Truth assert.*
com.google.common.truth.Truth8 assert.*
org.mockito.Mockito verify.*
org.mockito.InOrder verify
org.junit.rules.ExpectedException expect.*
org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert assertThat
```

Is there any "Maven" equivalent plugin which we can hook up to the build? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be a solution: https://jqassistant.org/find-junit-tests-without-assertions/  (this can do much more.)